# Linking css autcomplete with jsp content in Eclipse

Tags: css, eclipse, jsp

I'd like to know if it's possible, and if so how, to link the css autocomplete with the contents of a jsp page.

For example if I have  in the jsp I'd like to Eclipse autocomplete with "myid" when I write # on .css.

I know netbeans is capable of that but don't know about Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use it myself, so I can't say if it supports that, but try the [Eclipse Web Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/).

Comment: My eclipse is Indigo for Java EE so it already uses it..the css has autocompletion working but not linked with the .jsp content...which I'd like